# create table with shifted text

Tags: tables

can someone tell me, how can I create the following table?
[image]

In particular, how can I achieve that the text at the leftmost corner is shifted to the right? Here is my approach

```
\begin{tabular}{l  l  l  l}
\hline
\text{Nachfrager,Anbieter} & \text{viele} & \text{wenige} & \text{einer} \\ \hline 
\text{viele} & \text{polypol} & \text{Nachfrageoligopol} & \text{Nachfragemonopol} \\ \hline 
\text{wenige} & \text{Angebotsoligopol} & \text{bilaterales Oligopol} & \text{beschr\"anktes Nachfragemonopol} \\ \hline 
\text{einer} & \text{Angebotsmonopol} & \text{beschr\"anktes Angebotsmonopol} & \text{bilaterales Monopol} \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: If you provide the code example (except for that shift that you look for), it will require much less effort from people to answer.

Comment: Sorry! I have added my code

Comment: Can you please edit your MWE so that we can see what `packages` you are using and `documentclass`

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, using `tabularx` extension.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}{p{7em}XXX}
  \hline
\hfill  Nachfrager,\par Anbieter & viele & wenige & einer \\ \hline 
viele & polypol & Nachfrage-\par oligopol & Nachfrage-\par monopol \\ \hline 
wenige & Angebots-\par oligopol & bilaterales\par Oligopol & beschr\"anktes\par Nachfrage\par monopol \\ \hline 
einer & Angebots-\par monopol & beschr\"anktes\par Angebots-\par monopol & bilaterales\par Monopol \\ \hline 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabularx]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options: The first one is quite close to the image you included in your question. The second one is an alternative with less lines, clearer column headers and fewer line breaks inside of table cells:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l *{3}{>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2cm}}}
\toprule
\makecell[lt]{\qquad Nachfrager\\Anbieter} & viele & wenige & einer \\
\midrule
viele & Polypol & Nachfrageoligopol & Nachfragemonopol \\ \midrule
wenige & Angebotspolypol & bilaterales Oligopol & beschränktes Nachfragemonopol \\  \midrule
einer & Angebotsmonopol & beschränktes Angebotsmonopol & bilaterales Monopol\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip


\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\toprule
Anbieter & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Nachfrager}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
 & viele & wenige & einer \\
\midrule
viele & Polypol & Nachfrageoligopol & Nachfragemonopol \\ \addlinespace
wenige & Angebotspolypol & bilaterales Oligopol & \makecell{beschränktes\\ Nachfragemonopol} \\  \addlinespace
einer & Angebotsmonopol & \makecell{beschränktes\\ Angebotsmonopol} & bilaterales Monopol\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```